# Trouble integrating facebook authentication with cordova app

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, cordova, mobile

Sorry for the long post but I'm going nuts here..

I have been sitting with this issue for 3 days now - I am using Javascript to write a hybrid mobile app which I have integrated the Facebook Login button to. I have added the Openfb.js api to handle the login and the required functions in my master.js..

The facebook authentication is working perfectly, it opens the login page with the required for the specific app and allows you to login, returns "success" and you are redirected to the app again (inAppBrowser) but you do not get logged into the app and directed to the main.html page.. I am literally running in circles here and its driving me mad.

Below initiates the function when the facebook login button is clicked:

```
function facebookLogin() {
    showLoading(true);
    openFB.login(
        function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                getFacebookInfo();
                //showMessage('Facebook login succeeded, got access token: ' + response.authResponse.token);
            } else {
                showMessage('Facebook login failed: ' + response.error);
            }
        },
    { scope: 'email' });
}
```

Following this is the getFacebookInfo function:

```
    function getFacebookInfo() {
    openFB.api({
        path: '/me',
        success: function (facebookData) {
            debugger;
            var data = new Object();
            var now = new Date();

            var dataLogin = new Object();
            data.profilePicture = new Object();

            data.username = facebookData.first_name + ' ' + facebookData.last_name;
            data.password = randomPassword();

            console.log(data.username);
            data.email = facebookData.email;
            data.gender = facebookData.gender;
            data.firstName = facebookData.first_name;
            data.surname = facebookData.last_name;
            data.mode = 'facebook';
            var dt = new Date();
            data.dateOfBirth = dt.getFullYear() + '/' + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + dt.getDate();
            postData("users", data, successFacebookRegistration);
            //getData("users", dataLogin, successLogin);            
        },
        error: function (data, obj) {
            debugger;
            showMessage('An error occurred acquiring account information from Facebook');
        }
    });
}
```

The OpenFB.js is below:

```
    /**
 * OpenFB is a micro-library that lets you integrate your JavaScript application with Facebook.
 * OpenFB works for both BROWSER-BASED apps and CORDOVA/PHONEGAP apps.
 * This library has no dependency: You don't need (and shouldn't use) the Facebook SDK with this library. Whe running in
 * Cordova, you also don't need the Facebook Cordova plugin. There is also no dependency on jQuery.
 * OpenFB allows you to login to Facebook and execute any Facebook Graph API request.
 * @author Christophe Coenraets @ccoenraets
 * @version 0.4
 */
var openFB = (function () {

    var FB_LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
        FB_LOGOUT_URL = 'https://www.facebook.com/logout.php',

        // By default we store fbtoken in sessionStorage. This can be overridden in init()
        tokenStore = window.sessionStorage,

        fbAppId,

        context = window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/", 2)),

        baseURL = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '') + context,

        oauthRedirectURL = baseURL + '/oauthcallback.html',

        logoutRedirectURL = baseURL + '/logoutcallback.html',

        // Because the OAuth login spans multiple processes, we need to keep the login callback function as a variable
        // inside the module instead of keeping it local within the login function.
        loginCallback,

        // Indicates if the app is running inside Cordova
        runningInCordova,

        // Used in the exit event handler to identify if the login has already been processed elsewhere (in the oauthCallback function)
        loginProcessed;

    console.log(oauthRedirectURL);
    console.log(logoutRedirectURL);

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        runningInCordova = true;
    }, false);

    /**
     * Initialize the OpenFB module. You must use this function and initialize the module with an appId before you can
     * use any other function.
     * @param params - init paramters
     *  appId: The id of the Facebook app,
     *  tokenStore: The store used to save the Facebook token. Optional. If not provided, we use sessionStorage.
     */
    console.log("init");
    function init(params) {
        if (params.appId) {
            fbAppId = params.appId;
            if (params.cordova != null) {
                runningInCordova = params.cordova;
            }
        } else {
            throw 'appId parameter not set in init()';
        }

        if (params.tokenStore) {
            tokenStore = params.tokenStore;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the user has logged in with openFB and currently has a session api token.
     * @param callback the function that receives the loginstatus
     */
    console.log("getLoginStatus");
    function getLoginStatus(callback) {
        var token = tokenStore['fbtoken'],
            loginStatus = {};
        if (token) {
            loginStatus.status = 'connected';
            loginStatus.authResponse = { token: token };
        } else {
            loginStatus.status = 'unknown';
        }
        if (callback) callback(loginStatus);
    }

    /**
     * Login to Facebook using OAuth. If running in a Browser, the OAuth workflow happens in a a popup window.
     * If running in Cordova container, it happens using the In-App Browser. Don't forget to install the In-App Browser
     * plugin in your Cordova project: cordova plugins add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.
     *
     * @param callback - Callback function to invoke when the login process succeeds
     * @param options - options.scope: The set of Facebook permissions requested
     * @returns {*}
     */
    console.log("login");
    function login(callback, options) {
        var loginWindow,
            startTime,
            scope = '';

        if (!fbAppId) {
            return callback({ status: 'unknown', error: 'Facebook App Id not set.' });
        }

        // Inappbrowser load start handler: Used when running in Cordova only
        function loginWindow_loadStartHandler(event) {
            var url = event.url;
            if (url.indexOf("access_token=") > 0 || url.indexOf("error=") > 0) {
                // When we get the access token fast, the login window (inappbrowser) is still opening with animation
                // in the Cordova app, and trying to close it while it's animating generates an exception. Wait a little...
                var timeout = 600 - (new Date().getTime() - startTime);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    loginWindow.close();
                }, timeout > 0 ? timeout : 0);
                oauthCallback(url);
            }
        }

        // Inappbrowser exit handler: Used when running in Cordova only
        function loginWindow_exitHandler() {
            console.log('exit and remove listeners');
            // Handle the situation where the user closes the login window manually before completing the login process
            deferredLogin.reject({ error: 'user_cancelled', error_description: 'User cancelled login process', error_reason: "user_cancelled" });
            loginWindow.removeEventListener('loadstop', loginWindow_loadStartHandler);
            loginWindow.removeEventListener('exit', loginWindow_exitHandler);
            loginWindow = null;
            console.log('done removing listeners');
        }

        if (options && options.scope) {
            scope = options.scope;
        }

        loginCallback = callback;
        loginProcessed = false;

        //logout();

        if (runningInCordova) {
            oauthRedirectURL = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        }

        startTime = new Date().getTime();
        loginWindow = window.open(FB_LOGIN_URL + '?client_id=' + fbAppId + '&redirect_uri=' + oauthRedirectURL +
            '&response_type=token&scope=' + scope, '_blank', 'location=yes');

        // If the app is running in Cordova, listen to URL changes in the InAppBrowser until we get a URL with an access_token or an error
        if (runningInCordova) {
            loginWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', loginWindow_loadStartHandler);
            loginWindow.addEventListener('exit', loginWindow_exitHandler);
        }
        // Note: if the app is running in the browser the loginWindow dialog will call back by invoking the
        // oauthCallback() function. See oauthcallback.html for details.

    }

    /**
     * Called either by oauthcallback.html (when the app is running the browser) or by the loginWindow loadstart event
     * handler defined in the login() function (when the app is running in the Cordova/PhoneGap container).
     * @param url - The oautchRedictURL called by Facebook with the access_token in the querystring at the ned of the
     * OAuth workflow.
     */
    console.log("oauthCallback");
    function oauthCallback(url) {
        // Parse the OAuth data received from Facebook
        var queryString,
            obj;
        debugger;
        loginProcessed = true;
        if (url.indexOf("access_token=") > 0) {
            queryString = url.substr(url.indexOf('#') + 1);
            obj = parseQueryString(queryString);
            tokenStore['fbtoken'] = obj['access_token'];
            if (loginCallback) loginCallback({ status: 'connected', authResponse: { token: obj['access_token'] } });
        } else if (url.indexOf("error=") > 0) {
            queryString = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1, url.indexOf('#'));
            obj = parseQueryString(queryString);
            if (loginCallback) loginCallback({ status: 'not_authorized', error: obj.error });
        } else {
            if (loginCallback) loginCallback({ status: 'not_authorized' });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logout from Facebook, and remove the token.
     * IMPORTANT: For the Facebook logout to work, the logoutRedirectURL must be on the domain specified in "Site URL" in your Facebook App Settings
     *
     */
    console.log("logout");
    function logout(callback) {
        var logoutWindow,
            token = tokenStore['fbtoken'];

        /* Remove token. Will fail silently if does not exist */
        tokenStore.removeItem('fbtoken');

        if (token) {
            logoutWindow = window.open(FB_LOGOUT_URL + '?access_token=' + token + '&next=' + logoutRedirectURL, '_blank', 'location=yes');
            if (runningInCordova) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    logoutWindow.close();
                }, 700);
            }
        }

        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Lets you make any Facebook Graph API request.
     * @param obj - Request configuration object. Can include:
     *  method:  HTTP method: GET, POST, etc. Optional - Default is 'GET'
     *  path:    path in the Facebook graph: /me, /me.friends, etc. - Required
     *  params:  queryString parameters as a map - Optional
     *  success: callback function when operation succeeds - Optional
     *  error:   callback function when operation fails - Optional
     */
    console.log("api");
    function api(obj) {

        var method = obj.method || 'GET',
            params = obj.params || {},
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            url;

        console.log("access_token (api)");
        params['access_token'] = tokenStore['fbtoken'];

        url = 'https://graph.facebook.com' + obj.path + '?' + toQueryString(params);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    if (obj.success) obj.success(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                } else {
                    var error = xhr.responseText ? JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).error : { message: 'An error has occurred' };
                    if (obj.error) obj.error(error);
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.send();
    }

    /**
     * Helper function to de-authorize the app
     * @param success
     * @param error
     * @returns {*}
     */
    console.log("revokePermissions");
    function revokePermissions(success, error) {
        return api({
            method: 'DELETE',
            path: '/me/permissions',
            success: function () {
                tokenStore['fbtoken'] = undefined;
                success();
            },
            error: error
        });
    }

    function parseQueryString(queryString) {
        var qs = decodeURIComponent(queryString),
            obj = {},
            params = qs.split('&');
        params.forEach(function (param) {
            var splitter = param.split('=');
            obj[splitter[0]] = splitter[1];
        });
        return obj;
    }

    function toQueryString(obj) {
        var parts = [];
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                parts.push(encodeURIComponent(i) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[i]));
            }
        }
        return parts.join("&");
    }

    // The public API
    return {
        init: init,
        login: login,
        logout: logout,
        revokePermissions: revokePermissions,
        api: api,
        oauthCallback: oauthCallback,
        getLoginStatus: getLoginStatus
    }

}());
```

Finally then the postData is directed at the users api:

```
    <?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
require("json.php");    
require("utilities.php");    

class users extends rest_json_server{

    function get(){        
        $utils = new utilities();

        $mode           =   (isset($this->input['mode'])      ? $this->input['mode']      : '');
        $username       =   (isset($this->input['username'])  ? $this->input['username']  : '');
        $rawPassword    =   (isset($this->input['password'])  ? $this->input['password']  : '');
        $hashPassword   =   $utils->hash($rawPassword, null, true);
        $id             =   (isset($this->input['id'])        ? $this->input['id']        : '');

        if ($mode != 'recover'){
            $sql =  " SELECT *, ".
                    " (SELECT COUNT(p2.id) FROM posts p2 where p2.user_id = u.id) as totalPosts, ".
                    " (SELECT COUNT(f.id) FROM followings f where f.follower_id = u.id) as totalFollowings, ".
                    " (SELECT COUNT(f.id) FROM followings f where f.followed_id = u.id) as totalFollowers " .
                    " FROM users u ";

            $filter = '';

            if ($username != '' && $hashPassword != ''){
                $filter .= " WHERE (username = '" . $username . "' OR email = '" . $username . "') AND password = '" . $hashPassword . "' ";
            }
            else if ($id != ''){
                $filter .= " WHERE id = " . $id;
            }

            $result = $utils->useDatabase($sql . $filter);

            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 || $filter == '')
            {
                $this->response(200, 'Username and password combination not found');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->response(201, mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
            }
        }
        else {
            $sql = ' SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = \'' . $username . '\' OR email = \'' . $username . '\' ';

            $result = $utils->useDatabase($sql);

            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
            {
                $this->response(200, 'Username not found');
            }
            else
            {
                $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

                if (!$utils->sendEmail(
                    $result['email'], 
                    'Hi<br/><br/>' .
                    'Your password is: ' . $result['confirm'] .
                    '<br/><br/>' . 
                    'Best regards<br/>' .
                    'The Stylista team'))
                {
                    $this->response(500);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->response(201, 'Your password has been emailed to you');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function post(){
        $uploaddir = '../img/user-edit/';

        if (isset($_GET['file']))
        {
            $fileName = date('Ymdhis');
            foreach($_FILES as $file)
            {
                $fileName .= basename($file['name']);

                move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $fileName);
            }
            $this->response(201, $fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            $utils = new utilities();

            $username =     (isset($this->input_json->username) ? $this->input_json->username : '');
            $rawPassword =  (isset($this->input_json->password) ? $this->input_json->password : '');
            $hashedPassword = $utils->hash($rawPassword, null, true);
            $firstName =    (isset($this->input_json->firstName) ? $this->input_json->firstName : '');
            $surname =      (isset($this->input_json->surname) ? $this->input_json->surname : '');
            $email =        (isset($this->input_json->email) ? $this->input_json->email : '');
            $gender =       (isset($this->input_json->gender) ? $this->input_json->gender : '');
            $dateOfBirth =  (isset($this->input_json->dateOfBirth) ? $this->input_json->dateOfBirth : '');
            $country =      (isset($this->input_json->country) ? $this->input_json->country : '');
            $province =     (isset($this->input_json->province) ? $this->input_json->province : '');
            $city =         (isset($this->input_json->city) ? $this->input_json->city : '');
            $blogURL =      (isset($this->input_json->blogURL) ? $this->input_json->blogURL : '');
            $websiteURL =   (isset($this->input_json->websiteURL) ? $this->input_json->websiteURL : '');
            $id =           (isset($this->input_json->id) ? $this->input_json->id : '');
            $about =        (isset($this->input_json->about) ? $this->input_json->about : '');
            $profilePicFileName = '';
            $success        = true;
            $mode =         (isset($this->input_json->mode) ? $this->input_json->mode : '');
            $existsFacebook = false;
            $processSQL     = true;

            if (isset($this->input_json->profilePicture) && isset($this->input_json->profilePicture->imageData) && isset($this->input_json->profilePicture->fileName)){
                $profilePicFileName = $this->input_json->profilePicture->fileName;

                // Save profile picture
                $profilePicData = $this->input_json->profilePicture->imageData;
                $profilePicData = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $profilePicData);
                $profilePicData = str_replace(' ', '+', $profilePicData);
                $data = base64_decode($profilePicData);
                $file = $uploaddir . $profilePicFileName;
                $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
            }

            if (!$success){
                $processSQL = false;
                $this->response(500, 'Failed to save profile picture');
            }

            if ($username = '' || $firstName = '' || $surname = '' || $email = '') {
                $processSQL = false;
                $this->response(400, 'Certain fields are blank');
            }

            $result = $utils->useDatabase(" SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . $email . "' ");

            if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=0 && $id == '')
            {
                if ($mode == '')
                {
                    $processSQL = false;
                    $this->response(200,'Email exists');
                }
                else {
                    if ($id == '')
                    {
                        $id = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)['id'];
                    }

                    $existsFacebook = true;
                }
            }

            $result = $utils->useDatabase(" SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' ");

            if (mysql_num_rows($result)!=0 && $id == '')
            {
                if ($mode == '')
                {
                    $processSQL = false;
                    $this->response(200,'Username already exists');
                }
                else {
                    if ($id == '')
                    {
                        $id = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)['id'];
                    }

                    $existsFacebook = true;
                }
            }

            if ($processSQL)
            {
                $sql = '';

                if (($id == '' && $mode == '') || ($mode == 'facebook' && $existsFacebook == false)){
                    $sql =  " INSERT INTO users (password, created, modified, country, state_province, city, birthday, blog_url, website_url, email, first_name, last_name, username, email_ver, gender, confirm, banning, profile_pic) " .
                            " VALUES ('".$hashedPassword."', NOW(), NOW(), '".$country."', '".$province."', '".$city."', '".$dateOfBirth."', '".$blogURL."', '".$websiteURL."', '".$email."', '".$firstName."', '" .
                            $surname."', '".$username."', 1, '".$gender."', '".$rawPassword."', '', '" . $profilePicFileName . "')";

                    $result = $utils->useDatabase($sql);

                    $sql = 
                        " SELECT *, ".
                            " (SELECT COUNT(p2.id) FROM posts p2 where p2.user_id = u.id) as totalPosts, ".
                            " (SELECT COUNT(f.id) FROM followings f where f.follower_id = u.id) as totalFollowers, ".
                            " (SELECT COUNT(f.id) FROM followings f where f.followed_id = u.id) as totalFollowings " .
                        " FROM users u " .
                        " WHERE u.email = '" . $email . "'";

                    $result = $utils->useDatabase($sql);

                    $this->response(201, mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
                }
                else{
                    $updateSet = ($rawPassword != '' ? " password = '" . $hashedPassword ."', " : '') .
                            " modified = NOW(), ".
                            ($country != '' ? " country = '" . $country . "', " : '') .
                            ($province != '' ? " state_province= '" . $province . "', " : '') .
                            ($city != '' ? " city = '" . $city ."', " : '') .
                            ($dateOfBirth != '' ? " birthday = '" . $dateOfBirth ."', " : '') .
                            ($blogURL != '' ? " blog_url = '" . $blogURL . "', " : '') .
                            ($websiteURL != '' ? " website_url = '" . $websiteURL . "', " : '') .
                            ($email != '' ? " email = '" . $email . "', " : '') .
                            ($firstName != '' ? " first_name = '" . $firstName . "', " : '') .
                            ($surname != '' ? " last_name = '" . $surname . "', " : '') .
                            ($username != '' ? " username = '" . $username . "', " : '') .
                            ($gender != '' ? " gender = '" . $gender . "', " : '') .
                            ($about != '' ? " about = '" . $about . "', " : '') .
                            ($rawPassword != '' ? " confirm = '" . $rawPassword . "', " : '') .
                            ($profilePicFileName != '' ? " profile_pic = '" . $profilePicFileName . "', " : '');

                    $sql =
                        " UPDATE users " .
                        " SET " . 
                            substr($updateSet, 0, strlen($updateSet) - 2) .
                        " WHERE id = " . $id;

                    $result = $utils->useDatabase($sql);

                    $sql = 
                        " SELECT *, ".
                            " (SELECT COUNT(p2.id) FROM posts p2 where p2.user_id = u.id) as totalPosts, ".
                            " (SELECT COUNT(f.id) FROM followings f where f.follower_id = u.id) as totalFollowers, ".
                            " (SELECT COUNT(f.id) FROM followings f where f.followed_id = u.id) as totalFollowings " .
                        " FROM users u " .
                        " WHERE u.id = " . $id;

                    $result = $utils->useDatabase($sql);

                    $this->response(201, mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function put(){
        /**
         * No supported
         */
        $this->response(405);
    }


}

$start = new users();
$start->handle_request();
```

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's been my experience while using Cordova, that it does not play well with cookies and session states.  My hunch is that Facebook sets an authentication cookie - that gets instantly deleted.  *So you might be doing everything right, it's just that Cordova is bending you over.*

**So you might have to write a custom plugin that stores the Facebook authentication state outside of the webview.**

Are you targeting iOS or Android, or both?  I know on iOS it's actually easy to create a custom Facebook plugin to handle authentication (I did it myself).  It stores the authentication state *outside* of the webview and within the app data itself, so that even when switching pages it'll remember the authentication state.

It should be stated that after doing substantial work in my iOS Cordova app, the multiple flaws of Cordova were starting to snowball... and decided to just write it natively.

**CUSTOM PLUGIN FOR IOS**

This assumes you have an idea on how plugins work for Cordova on iOS.  Also includes code on how to share a workout activity on someone's wall ;)

*Facebook.h*

```
#import <Cordova/CDVCommandDelegate.h>
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>

@interface FacebookPlugin : CDVPlugin <FBSDKSharingDelegate>

- (void) IsLoggedIn:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command;
- (void) LoginWithReadPermissions:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command;
- (void) LoginWithWritePermissions:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command;
- (void) Logout:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command;
@end
```

*Facebook.m*

```
#import "Facebook.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction.h>

@implementation FacebookPlugin

// [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil] and [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil].

- (void) IsLoggedIn:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    FBSDKAccessToken* token = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
    NSString* stringResult;

    if (token != nil)
    {
        stringResult = @"YES";
    } else {
        stringResult = @"NO";
    }

    CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:stringResult];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

- (void) Logout:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logOut];
}

- (void) LoginWithReadPermissions:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
                CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
                [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
          } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
                [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
          } else {
                CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
                [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
          }
    }];
}

- (void) LoginWithWritePermissions:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
         CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
         [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
    } else {
        FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [login logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
              if (error) {
                    CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
                    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                    CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
                    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
              } else {

                    // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                    // should check if specific permissions missing
                    if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"]) {
                        CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
                        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
                    } else {
                        CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
                        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
                    }
              }
        }];
    };
}

- (void) ShareWorkout:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSDictionary* options = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0 withDefault:nil];

    //get the app id
    NSString *appId = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"FacebookAppID"];

    // Create an object
    NSDictionary *properties = @{
        @"fb:app_id": appId,
        @"og:type": @"fitness.course",
        @"og:url": [options objectForKey:@"websiteURL"],
        @"og:title": [options objectForKey:@"courseTitle"],
        @"og:image": [options objectForKey:@"logoURL"],
        //@"fitness:duration:value": [options objectForKey:@"workoutDuration"],
        //@"fitness:duration:value": [options objectForKey:@"workoutDurationUnit"],
        //@"fitness:custom_unit_energy:value": [options objectForKey:@"workoutCalories"],
        //@"fitness:custom_unit_energy:units": [options objectForKey:@"workoutCalorieUnit"]
    };

    FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *graphObject = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

    // Create an action [fitness.runs, fitness.walks for actionType]
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
    action.actionType = [options objectForKey:@"actionType"];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    [action setObject:graphObject forKey:@"fitness:course"];
    //[action setString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] forKey:@"created_time"];
    [action setObject:[options objectForKey:@"userMessage"] forKey:@"message"];
    [action setString:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];
    //[action setString:[options objectForKey:@"workoutStart"] forKey:@"start_time"];

    FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
    content.action = action;
    content.previewPropertyName = @"fitness:course";

    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self.viewController withContent:content delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark === delegate method
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{
    NSLog(@"completed share:%@", results);
}

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"sharing error:%@", error);
    NSString *message = error.userInfo[FBSDKErrorLocalizedDescriptionKey] ?:
    @"There was a problem sharing, please try again later.";
    NSString *title = error.userInfo[FBSDKErrorLocalizedTitleKey] ?: @"Oops!";

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}

- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer
{
    NSLog(@"share cancelled");
}

@end
```

*Facebook.js*

```
var Facebook = function() {}

cordova.addConstructor(function() {
    console.log('initializing Facebook');
    if (!window.Cordova) {
        window.Cordova = cordova;
    };

    if(!window.plugins) window.plugins = {};
    window.plugins.Facebook = new Facebook();
});


    Facebook.prototype.LoginWithReadPermissions = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
            return cordova.exec(
                    function() {
                        successCallback();
                    }, 
                    function() {
                        errorCallback();
                    },
                    'FacebookPlugin', 'LoginWithReadPermissions', []);

    };

    Facebook.prototype.LoginWithWritePermissions = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
            return cordova.exec(
                    function() {
                        successCallback();
                    }, 
                    function() {
                        errorCallback();
                    },
                    'FacebookPlugin', 'LoginWithWritePermissions', []);

    };

     Facebook.prototype.Logout = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
            return cordova.exec(
                    function() {

                    }, 
                    function() {

                    },
                    'FacebookPlugin', 'Logout', []);

    };

    Facebook.prototype.ShareWorkout = function(successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
            return cordova.exec(
                    function() {
                        successCallback();
                    }, 
                    function() {
                        errorCallback();
                    },
                    'FacebookPlugin', 'ShareWorkout', [options]);

    };
```

Comment: Haha excellent italic reply!

Could it possibly when it switches from the inAppBrowser to the app it loses the authentication state? I tested the returning of the token which was there when it redirected back to the app.
I am building for both iOS and for Android, it will also be used on Blackberry (don't get me started on my issues there) and also on Windows phones..
Mind giving me a sample to look at?

Comment: I think I found the issue with the Facebook authentication - the UpdateSET is not working as it should thus when you select to login with Facebook, you are given an auto gen'd password - the API then checks if a record with your email address already exists and if so it should update your password with the new gen'd one.. However it is not thus the password/username combination is always wrong.. SIGH!